# Xcode 9.4.1: timed out after 0.012s (suspension count=0 (Suspensions: )

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

So whenever I run the app I get this error message below. Can someone help to fix it step by step or give a general idea on how to deal with it?

> timed out after 0.012s (78 79); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )

[image]

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.4.1 and have the same problem on a simulator but not on my iPhone 7.